# Siamese network accuracy stuck after adding more training data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am new to machine learning and I am currently trying to create a siamese network that can predict the similarity of brand logos.
I have a dataset with ~210.000 brand logos.
The CNN for the siamese network looks like the following:

```
def build_cnn(inputShape, embeddingDim=48):
# specify the inputs for the feature extractor network
inputs = Input(shape=inputShape)
# define the first set of CONV => RELU => POOL => DROPOUT layers
x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5))(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

# second set of CONV => RELU => POOL => DROPOUT layers
x = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding="same", activation="relu")(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(x)
x = Dropout(0.3)(x)

pooledOutput = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
outputs = Dense(embeddingDim)(pooledOutput)
# build the model
model = Model(inputs, outputs)
model.summary()
plot_model(model, to_file=os.path.sep.join([config.BASE_OUTPUT,'model_cnn.png']))
# return the model to the calling function
return model
```

[image: CNN]

The siamese network looks like this (the model here is the cnn described above):

```
imgA = Input(shape=config.IMG_SHAPE)
imgB = Input(shape=config.IMG_SHAPE)
featureExtractor = siamese_network.build_cnn(config.IMG_SHAPE)
featsA = featureExtractor(imgA)
featsB = featureExtractor(imgB)
distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([featsA, featsB])
outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
model = Model(inputs=[imgA, imgB], outputs=outputs)
```

[image: Siamese Network]

My first test was with 800 positive and 800 negative pairs and the accuracy and loss looks like this:
[image: Accuracy and Training]

My thoughts to this were that there is some overfitting happening and my approach was to create more training data (2000 positive and negative pairs) and train the model again, but unfortunately the model was not improving at all after, even after 20+ epochs.

[image: Training with more data]

For both cases I used the following to train my network:

```
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
print("[INFO] training model...")
history = model.fit(
    [pairTrain[:, 0], pairTrain[:, 1]], labelTrain[:],
    validation_data=([pairTest[:, 0], pairTest[:, 1]], labelTest[:]),
    batch_size=10,
    shuffle=True,
    epochs=50)
```

I cannot figure out what is happening here, so I am really gratefull for every help.
My question here is why is the siamese network learning (or at least it looks like it is learning) with less training data, but as soon as I add more the accuracy is constant and not improving at all?

**EDIT**
According to Albertos comment I tried it with selu (still not working):

[image]

**EDIT2**
With LeakyReLU it looks like this:

[image]

My latest training result with 10k Pairs looks like this:

[image: Training 10k Pairs]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen this happening other times, idk if it's a case but [this Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/56867) issue has literally the same loss

As in that case, I think that is more a problem of initialization, so at this point I think you should use He-initialziation, or non-saturating activation function (for example, try `tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU` or `tf.keras.activations.selu`)

Comment: With LeakyReLU it is looking really good so far!

Comment: @DavidWalser happy to see that it's working, let me know, and in case it works, good luck with you project

Comment: I added the training progress with LeakyReLU to the question, looks ok but somehow stuck at ~86%

Comment: @DavidWalser at this point, I think you can go on with LeakyRelu, and improve your model.. maybe it just gets stuck because that's its memory capacity, and as far as i can see, there are no sign of overfitting

Comment: yes I am totally with you, thank you very much!

Comment: @DavidWalser you're welcome... just as a side note, are you sure you are training it in graph mode and using GPU acceleration? because the epochs' time look very strange, you are not training an absurd size model, thus it should take much less than 15 minutes per epoch

Comment: yes thank you, it was faster with GPU! Do you have any suggestions for my latest training/accuracy graph? The results seem really random and kind of the same as with 800 pairs